# How to access objects/arrays defined in JavaScript from Java applets

Tags: javascript, java, applet

Using LiveConnect getMember(String) method of a window JSObject, a Java object of type "Object" is returned, but I don't find the expected members defined on it. Neither can I cast it to a JSObject to continue using the getMember().

Accessing DOM nodes and elements (DOM Objects) works as expected.

Comment: It's rather unclear what exactly you're trying to do - how about showing us some sourcecode?

Comment: When you say you can't cast, do you get a specific exception or error ?

Comment: @andynormancx

Yes. That processing cannot cast from Object to JSObject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the line `got2 = win.getMember("obj");`. It seems like you're expecting that line to get the `foo` object. As I understand it, `win.getMember("obj")` will get you the `obj` property on the DOM `window` node, which doesn't exist. For example, from [this page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html#how):

```
JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
JSObject doc = (JSObject) win.getMember("document");
JSObject loc = (JSObject) doc.getMember("location");
```

If you want to get the `foo` object, the best way I'm aware of is to make a JavaScript method you can call from the Java applet.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = {"one":1, "two":2};

function getFoo() { return foo; }
</script>
```

**Applet:**

```
import netscape.javascript.*;
JSObject win;
JSObject foo;

void setup(){
  size(400,200,P2D);
  background(255);
  win  = JSObject.getWindow(this); //gets the root JSObject
  foo = (JSObject)win.call("getFoo", null);
}

void draw(){
  if (mousePressed == true){
    println(foo.getMember("one"));
  }
}
```

Comment: MDC says that it's supposed to be a "JavaScript Object". Whatever that means.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/LiveConnect/JSObject

Comment: Yes, but I don't get why you expect it to get the "foo" object. "JavaScript object" just means it's a object from JavaScript that's been translated to a Java object, specifically JSObject.

Comment: It did. What's your exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at js_processing_api.draw(js_processing_api.java:34)
 at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1406)
 at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1311)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Random guess: try clearing your classloader cache? Bring up your Java console (Tools - Java console in FF, or right click on the Java icon in your systray and pick the console), and hit x to clear it, then reload.

Comment: I did try that. It throws the error when I click on the applet.

Comment: I'm not sure I have any more suggestions for you, except to be pedantic - are you using the exact code I wrote above? I can get the exception if I have getFoo return null, but my line number is 32 instead of 34, so I suspect you have something else there as well.

Comment: It works now. Thanks.. I don't know what the error was but I copy pasted your code and viola it works. Thanks a ton.

Comment: There's another problem, how may I assign it the values I get to a variable. The type appears to be an Object and I can't cast it to float or string.