# How can I programatically test which CSS elements match my XHTML?

Tags: java, css, unit-testing

I have an application which generates XHTML documents which are styled with (mostly) static CSS. I'm currently using XPath and Hamcrest (Java) to verify that the documents are constructed correctly. However, I also need to verify that the correct CSS properties are matched. For example, I would like a test like this:

Given XHTML element Foo, verify that the property "text-transform:uppercase" is applied.

Ideally, I would like a Java framework that provides this. I've looked a bit at Selenium, but I don't see this type of functionality. Thanks ...

Comment: This is a really neat queation - great first post!

Comment: Thanks Eamon :) Posting on this site is close to a last resort -- I've seen lots of other good answers to questions on this site, and hope this can find one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Javascript, using the getStyle() code as [described on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I see how the currentStyle attribute / getComputedStyle method can be used from javascript. The problem then becomes how do I call javascript from Java? I'm hoping that I can do this with Rhino.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515417/how-to-access-objects-arrays-defined-in-javascript-from-java-applets

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/) to do this for you very easily. It is not a java framework, but it will work on any webapps, and IMO it is better than Selenium.

Comment: Windmill seems heavyweight for what I need. If I can get this value with simply javascript, that should be enough.